# Save purchace order and product list

Tags: database, model, laravel-4, purchase-order

Good Day,

---

Can anyone help me please on how to figure this one out..
Im creating a purchase order module on my project and this modules saves the data into 2 different tables at the same time, which are tblPurchaseOrder_order and tblProductList, but i need to get the purchase order id which will be generated automatically once the data is saved in the tblPurchaseOrder so that I can save it on the tblProductList as the reference id of the new products.

here's what my form looks like: [image]

my opinion is:
I save first the data in tblPurchaseOrder then retrieve that id, then save the products on the tblProductList with the id I retrieved, would it be okay if i do that?

by the way im using laravel4

Your help would really be appreciated.. thank you for TIME :3
Best Regards..
-Melvn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your DB, once your first insert occurs it could be returning a value - the last inserted id. If so, you can use this in a join to get the purchase order id for your second insert.

Comment: Thank you @A.M.D for your answer.. Cleared some vague thoughts about it.. I think its the only way on how to do that!

Comment: Indeed, if your DB will return the value as the result of your insert it saves you having to do that intermediate query. I don't know Laravel at all, but this should help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php